# How to grant sudo permission for a .py script on a apache folder?

Tags: linux, sudo, python, apache-httpd, cgi

I've `exemplo.py` in an folder `/opt/lampp/htdocs/cgi-local/exemplo.py` folder. The script creates a socket that needs super user permissions.

My question was a little confusing? I need to access `localhost/cgi-local/exemplo.py`. The script must have super user permissions, that is, it must be free to create a socket in apache

Comment: With 'sudo python exemplo.py' like every other command?!

Comment: No @tkausl. The script is accessible via browser, http://dominio.com/pasta/exemplo.py Entering the link the command executed requires superuser permissions.

see the code,

 #!/usr/bin/python
import socket, sys
from struct import *
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print
print '<html><head>'
...